# Solve a sequence of incomplete sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My uni is closed because of the pandemic and I'm home learning calculus. There is one problem I am really not sure how is supposed to be solved:

$$\log(x)+\log(\sqrt[3]{x})+\log(\sqrt[9]{x})+\log(\sqrt[27]{x})+\ldots=6$$

I know that I am supposed to show my attempts, but this is the first time I am seeing a problem like this and I have no idea how to solve it.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$log (x)+log(\sqrt[3]{x})+log(\sqrt[9]{x})+log(\sqrt[27]{x})+...= log (x)+ \frac 1 3 log(x)+ \frac 1 9log(x)+ \frac 1 {27} log(x)+... $$

---

**Full answer :**

Let's massage the expression. This equality is given by geometric sum, and taking the limit of the expression.
$$ log (x)+log(\sqrt[3]{x})+ ...  = \log(x) \sum_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {3^n} =  \frac 3 2 \log(x)   $$

so finally, you're simply searching for $$  \log(x) = 4 $$
Can you find the answer to that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use properties of log to rewrite the equation as
$$\log x + \frac{1}{3}\log x  + \frac{1}{9}\log x + \frac{1}{27}\log x + \dots = 6.$$
Equivalently,
$$\log x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k = 6.$$
Next sum the geometric series to obtain
$$\log x \cdot\frac{1}{1-1/3} = 6.$$
Now $\log x = 4$, so $x = e^4$ (or $x=10^4$ if your $\log$ means $\log_{10}$).